# generate PHP's array that came from explode into html

Tags: php, html

I have an array based my query like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID_REQUEST] => 28
        [DEPARTEMENT] => IT
        [company] => TMS
        [BULAN] => 03
        [NUMBER_OF_LETTER] => 008
        [NAMA_TIPE] => Perbaikan
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 2
        [first_name] => Ahmad
        [last_name] => Fadly
        [TANGGAL_PERSETUJUAN] => 
        [TANGGAL_TERIMA] => 2016-03-26 00:00:00
        [PERKIRAAN_SELESAI] => 2016-03-26 00:00:00
        [TANGGAL_SELESAI] => 
        [PELAKSANA] => Dzil
        [KELUHAN] => Test
        [CATATAN] => Saja
        [nama_departement] => IT
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID_REQUEST] => 5
        [DEPARTEMENT] => IT
        [company] => TMS
        [BULAN] => 03
        [NUMBER_OF_LETTER] => 003
        [NAMA_TIPE] => Permintaan
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 6
        [first_name] => Indah
        [last_name] => Kurnia
        [TANGGAL_PERSETUJUAN] => 2016-03-25 08:00:00
        [TANGGAL_TERIMA] => 2016-03-25 09:00:00
        [PERKIRAAN_SELESAI] => 2016-03-25 10:00:00
        [TANGGAL_SELESAI] => 2016-03-25 11:00:00
        [PELAKSANA] => Dzil
        [KELUHAN] => Refill toner 85 A
        [CATATAN] => Sudah di refill
        [nama_departement] => LCL
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID_REQUEST] => 4
        [DEPARTEMENT] => IT
        [company] => TMS
        [BULAN] => 03
        [NUMBER_OF_LETTER] => 002
        [NAMA_TIPE] => Perbaikan, Permintaan
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 1,2,3,4,5,6
        [first_name] => Hud
        [last_name] => Adityawan
        [TANGGAL_PERSETUJUAN] => 2016-03-25 03:00:00
        [TANGGAL_TERIMA] => 2016-03-24 03:00:00
        [PERKIRAAN_SELESAI] => 2016-03-25 03:00:00
        [TANGGAL_SELESAI] => 2016-03-25 04:00:00
        [PELAKSANA] => Awan
        [KELUHAN] => Minta naik gaji dong
        [CATATAN] => Iya, go ahead. Appproved
        [nama_departement] => IT
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID_REQUEST] => 3
        [DEPARTEMENT] => IT
        [company] => JFS
        [BULAN] => 03
        [NUMBER_OF_LETTER] => 001
        [NAMA_TIPE] => Perbaikan
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 2,3,4,5
        [first_name] => Yakub
        [last_name] => Yusuf
        [TANGGAL_PERSETUJUAN] => 2016-03-25 03:00:00
        [TANGGAL_TERIMA] => 2016-03-24 03:00:00
        [PERKIRAAN_SELESAI] => 2016-03-25 03:00:00
        [TANGGAL_SELESAI] => 2016-03-25 04:00:00
        [PELAKSANA] => Dzil
        [KELUHAN] => Mohon diperiksa login novell saya karena saya tidak bisa login
        [CATATAN] => Akan kami cek jaringan tersebut
        [nama_departement] => Ekspor
    )

)
```

Please see on `[NAMA_ITEM]`. This is the simple view perhaps.

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 2
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 6
)

[2] => stdClass Object
(
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 1,2,3,4,5,6
)
[3] => stdClass Object
(
        [NAMA_ITEM] => 2,3,4,5,6
)
```

If you see, This string be explode into an array based `,` delimiter.

In html. My code looked like this :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" id="table-request" width="100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>No</th>
         <th>Nomor Request</th>
         <th>Jenis Request</th>
         <th>L</th>  // FOR CODE 1 
         <th>P</th>  // FOR CODE 2
         <th>M</th>  // FOR CODE 3
         <th>C</th>  // FOR CODE 4
         <th>N</th>  // FOR CODE 5
         <th>LL</th> // FOR CODE 6
         <th>Nama</th>
         <th>Dept</th>
         <th>Tgl / Jam Permintaan</th>
         <th>Tgl / Jam Penerimaan</th>
         <th>Tgl / Jam Perkiraan</th>
         <th>Tgl / Jam Selesai</th>
         <th>Pelaksana</th>
         <th>Uraian Keluhan</th>
          <th>Tindakan Yang Diambil</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
```

This is my representated :

```
<tbody>

<?php                    
foreach ($coba as $key => $row):
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
  echo "<td>$row->DEPARTEMENT/$row->company/$row->BULAN/$row->NUMBER_OF_LETTER </td>";
  echo "<td>$row->NAMA_TIPE </td>";

  **// The Problem**
  $nama_item = explode(",", $row->NAMA_ITEM);
  foreach ($nama_item as $key => $v):
    echo "<td>v</td>";
  endforeach;

  echo "</tr>";
endforeach;
?>

</tbody>
```

The result is like this :

```
+----------------------------------------+
| L | P     | M | C | N | LL     |  NAMA |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2 | AHMAD |   |   |   |        |       |
| 6 | INDAH |   |   |   |        |       |
| 1 | 2     | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6      |  HUD  | 
| 2 | 3     | 4 | 5 | 6 | YAKUB  |       |
+----------------------------------------+
```

It lookeds so awkward. I need like this :

```
 +--------------------------------+
 | L | P | M | C | N | LL | NAMA  |
 +--------------------------------+
 |   | 2 |   |   |   |    | AHMAD |
 |   |   |   |   |   | 6  | INDAH |
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6  | HUD   |
 |   | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6  | YAKUB |
 +--------------------------------+
```

It looked simple, but I have stacked for one hour. For the help, it so appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your `NAMA_ITEM` contains the item indexes that should be assigned, so I would do this instead:

```
$nama_item = explode(",", $row->NAMA_ITEM);
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 6 ; ++$i):
  echo in_array($i, $nama_item) ? "<td>$i</td>" : "<td></td>";
endfor;
```

So what this means is you always loop through 6 indexes, and only when the index exist (in_array) of the array of `$nama_item`, you echo it. Else, echo the empty `td` to pad it out.